# Euclidean Distance Error: unsupported operand type

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to implement `euclidean distance` using `scipy.spatial.distance` which i have previously written normally like this.

```
from math import sqrt

critics = {'Lisa Rose': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
                         'Just My Luck': 3.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5,
                         'The Night Listener': 3.0},
           'Gene Seymour': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
                            'Just My Luck': 1.5, 'Superman Returns': 5.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0,
                            'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5},
           'Michael Phillips': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.0,
                                'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'The Night Listener': 4.0},
           'Claudia Puig': {'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5, 'Just My Luck': 3.0,
                            'The Night Listener': 4.5, 'Superman Returns': 4.0,
                            'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5},
           'Mick LaSalle': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 4.0,
                            'Just My Luck': 2.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0,
                            'You, Me and Dupree': 2.0},
           'Jack Matthews': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 4.0,
                             'The Night Listener': 3.0, 'Superman Returns': 5.0, 'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5},
           'Toby': {'Snakes on a Plane': 4.5, 'You, Me and Dupree': 1.0, 'Superman Returns': 4.0}}


def sim_distance(preference, person1, person2):
    si = {}
    for item in preference[person1]:
        if item in preference[person2]:
            si[item] = 1

    if len(si) == 0: return 0

    sum_of_scores = sum([pow(preference[person1][item] - preference[person2][item], 2)
                         for item in preference[person1] if item in preference[person2]])

    return 1 / (1 + sum_of_scores)


a = sim_distance(critics, 'Lisa Rose','Mick LaSalle')
print(a) #0.333
```

Current implementation works perfectly but when tried using `scipy` module, i am not able to understand what type of input should be provided for that. This is what i tried.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean


a = euclidean(critics['Lisa Rose'], critics['Mick LaSalle'])
print(a)
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ajay/PycharmProjects/SO/new.py", line 22, in <module>
    a = euclidean(critics['Lisa Rose'], critics['Mick LaSalle'])
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py", line 224, in euclidean
    dist = norm(u - v)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'dict' and 'dict'
```

When referred to the `euclidean` implementation, it seems the input should be given as `tuples` but i am not able to understand how to process this.

```
def euclidean(u, v):
    """
    Computes the Euclidean distance between two 1-D arrays.

    The Euclidean distance between 1-D arrays `u` and `v`, is defined as

    .. math::

       {||u-v||}_2

    Parameters
    ----------
    u : (N,) array_like
        Input array.
    v : (N,) array_like
        Input array.

    Returns
    -------
    euclidean : double
        The Euclidean distance between vectors `u` and `v`.

    """
    u = _validate_vector(u)
    v = _validate_vector(v)
    dist = norm(u - v)
    return dist
```

Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euclidean distance is defined as a L2 norm of the difference between two vectors, which you can see as `dist = norm(u - v)` in `euclidean` function. Your `critics['Lisa Rose']` and `critics['Mick LaSalle']` are dictionaries and `-` (subtraction) operation is not defined for dictionary data type. Also, `norm` is defined for an array-like data type.

Thus, if you really need to use `scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean` for your case, you need create a class for your `critics` and in your class, you need to overload `-` operator by defining `__sub__` method, which returns an array-like data type.

Comment: Whats the best case to find the distance then?

Comment: what do you mean? It depends on how you define distance.

Answer (score 0):

I made a nice API for that with ugly code:

http://vectordict.readthedocs.org/en/latest/vector.html#metrics

IMPORTANT: I don't recommend using this code at all (I am rewriting it correctly), just see how it works and maybe respect the API but do not use the code.

By overwriting +/-/*/ / the "linear algebraic way you may be interested in how you can go back to do «math» with dict and how it can be implemented, and how it makes life easier.

Here is the implementation of L2 norm : sqrt( self.dot(self) )

https://github.com/jul/ADictAdd_iction/blob/master/vector_dict/VectorDict.py#L972

I advocate using API that are consistent with linear algebrae definitions on objects so it is easier to make sense of what you read.

```
from vector_dict.VectorDict import cos
from vector_dict.VectorDict import convert_tree, VectorDict
crit = {'Lisa Rose': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
                         'Just My Luck': 3.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5,
                         'The Night Listener': 3.0},
           'Gene Seymour': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
                            'Just My Luck': 1.5, 'Superman Returns': 5.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0,
                            'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5},
           'Michael Phillips': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.0,
                                'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'The Night Listener': 4.0},
           'Claudia Puig': {'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5, 'Just My Luck': 3.0,
                            'The Night Listener': 4.5, 'Superman Returns': 4.0,
                            'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5},
           'Mick LaSalle': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 4.0,
                            'Just My Luck': 2.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0,
                            'You, Me and Dupree': 2.0},
           'Jack Matthews': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 4.0,
                             'The Night Listener': 3.0, 'Superman Returns': 5.0, 'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5},
           'Toby': {'Snakes on a Plane': 4.5, 'You, Me and Dupree': 1.0, 'Superman Returns': 4.0}}
dd = convert_tree(crit)
print "cos"
print cos(dd['Gene Seymour'], dd['Toby'])
# 0.770024275094
print "L2 distance"
print dd['Gene Seymour'].norm()
# 8.35164654425    
print "jaccard similarities"
print dd['Gene Seymour'].jaccard( dd['Toby'])
# 0.579335793358
```

PS I guessed that if you were making norm calculus, it was for making comparaison, and I jumped to the conclusion you want to do similarity measurements.

Comment: Its great. i will fork the repo and try to contribute :)

Comment: The new rewrite is here, in fact.
https://github.com/jul/archery
Using a defaultdict at my opinion is less interesting than traits.
The naming in archery is stupid, I have to make a total renaming of the stuff (I mean, I can't even remember myself the naming convention).
I stopped working on it when I felt on the / problem. But, glitches in packaging with py3 really held me back for month so I stopped working on it. I am clueless on the py3 vs py2 war.